# Connecting Two Windows Server via SSH - Ant

Tags: windows, ant, ssh, server

Hope things going good.

I want to connect two windows server using ssh.But, My problem is, when I use the ANT task 'sshexec' to execute a .bat file from a remote WINDOWS server 2009 like this:

```
<sshexec host="10.46.220.108"
username="support"
password="India123"
 trust="true" 
verbose="true"
command="D:\project\jboss-eap-6.1\bin\standalone.bat -b hostname41" />
```

My execution gets hanged and stops with the below lines.

```
 [sshexec] Connecting to hostname:22
[sshexec] cmd :D:\project\jboss-eap-6.1\bin\standalone.bat -b hostname41
[sshexec] Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
[sshexec] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[sshexec] C:\users\administrator>
```

Guide me to resolve this.

**NOTE: The remote server is running copssh in port number 22**